# cron script restore backup from s3 not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cron

Have a shell script that pulls the latest backup from aws s3.  It is working fine.  But when I use cron to schedule the restore, it does not run.  From looking at the output, there is some problem with assigning the variable FILE.  I am not sure why cron is behave differently.

From the echo, the value for $FILE is empty

Any help would be appreciated.

```
BUCKET="s3://mysite-backup"
FILE=`aws s3 ls $BUCKET --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'`
echo $BUCKET
echo $FILE

/usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp $BUCKET/$FILE /data/restore_dir
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron doesn't have all the environment variables you have in your shell, so `/usr/local/bin` may not be on cron's `PATH`. Try specifying the full path to `aws`:

```
FILE=`/usr/local/bin/aws s3 ls $BUCKET --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'`
```

Comment: Hi @user1774599, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.